# My WFFM submits do not appear in lists

Tags: xdb, wffm

I have a WFFM form which collects some contact info. The info is correctly persisted in xDB and the contact can be found in the experience profile.
One of my save actions is to add the contact to a list, specifically created for this form.

The form save actions all succeed, but somehow the contact does not appear in my list. (when exporting from form report the user is in there, so that part also works)

I use Sitecore 8.2 update 5 and I have a separate processing server configured which I assume should take care of showing my contacts in the created lists, is that a correct assumption?

On my processing server I do see following warning right after a form submit:

> Ignoring unknown event: Sitecore.Form.Core.WffmActionEvent,
>   Sitecore.Forms.Core, Version=8.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null, instance: Sitecore.Form.Core.WffmActionEvent,
>   Sitecore.Forms.Core, Version=8.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null, sender: [CD-NODE1]

I followed the guide as available [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/39EE90F91B66474597B2B510BB924EBF.ashx):

So I added the three assemblies to my processing instance and the appropriate config file +changes for CM/CD servers.

Any good suggestions what I could dig into next?

**UPDATE:**
Reindexing forced the list to get into a weird state to tell it has 1 out of 0 indexed contacts, but still show nothing.
In addition I found out that form report export contains correct data. Contact list export contains 1 contact while there are more.

Any explanation on how to list filling/linking works would also be helpful so I have a better idea in which area's to investigate.

Comment: Can you try rebuilding your indexes ?

Comment: hmm, now it shows:
Please note that contacts in the list are currently being indexed, so not all contacts are available to view at this time. 1 out of 0 contacts are currently indexed.

which is kind of a weird warning if you think about it.

Comment: I'll wait a bit and see what happens, but also my form report seems to be off, not showing anything, while form report export does have 1 contact. Very odd

Comment: After the weekend, not progress. also weird differences, report/export give 3 contacts, list shows nothing but on exports contains 1 contact.

Answer (score 3):

After some much needed and highly appreciated help from Pete Navarra I found out that Sitecore WFFM installation guide is missing crucial information. For processing server not only the following assemblies should be added:
According to: https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/39EE90F91B66474597B2B510BB924EBF.ashx

\Website\bin\Sitecore.WFFM.dll

\Website\bin\Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.dll

\Website\bin\Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.dll

but also:
Sitecore.Forms.Core.dll

With this assembly proper event handling is in place and the list tag is added to the xDB contact.

**UPDATE**
The MSCaptcha.dll and Sitecore.WFFM.Actions.dll also have to be copied to Processing server if you experience any error about missing assembly.

Comment: This is still an issue in sitecore 9.0.2

Comment: After I uploaded Sitedore.Forms.Core.dll to Processing server I got some error. I had to upload MSCaptcha.dll and Sitecore.WFFM.Actions.dll to fix it.